# How to Set Dropdown Value with dom-repeat

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, dom-repeat

I am trying to select the second option form a dropdown if specific conditions are met, am having problems with the `selectedIndex`

```
<select id="contact" on-change="selectContact">
  <option  value="-1" selected>Select Contact</option>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[contacts]]" as="contact" index-as="index">
     <option value="[[contact]]">[[contact]]</option>
  </template>
</select>

<select id="name" on-change="selectName">
  <option  value="-1" selected>Select Name</option>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[names]]" as="name">
      <option value="[[name]]">[[name]]</option>
    </template>
</select>
```

...

```
selectContact() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.customerTable[0].length; i++) {
    if(true) {
        array[i] = this.customerTable[0][i]['name'];
      }
  }
  this.names = this.$.util.utilFn(array);


  if(this.names.length == 1) {
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#name').selectedIndex = 2;
  }

}
```

How can I select the second child of a dom-repeat dropdown?

Comment: That works for me. [demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/eVMmJv?editors=1010) What's the rest of your code look like?

Comment: The selector is wrapped in an if statement, so is undefined when using `this.$.name`.

Comment: Using `querySelector` also works for me. See updated demo.

Comment: I'm puzzled... not seeing any typos in my own code.

Comment: It might help to post more code to show context. It would be most helpful to provide a Codepen that reproduces the problem.

Comment: OK.  Made some more edits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `selectContact()`, you're setting `this.names` (to which the second `<dom-repeat>.items` is bound) and immediately attempting to select the first item of that `<dom-repeat>` before the DOM has actually updated.

You actually need to wait until the next render frame with [`Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/namespaces/Polymer.RenderStatus) before selecting the item:

```
selectContact() {
  this.names = ['John'];

  if (this.names.length === 1) {
    Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender(this, () => {
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#name').selectedIndex = 1;
    });
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/eVMmJv?editors=1010)